# Drive not able to be added to Storage Spaces

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, storage, storage-spaces

I am having difficulties trying to create a storage space.

I have four Hard Drives in my computer.

- Samsung 128Gb SSD x2
- Caviar Green 2TB
- Older 320 Gb drive

I want to *merge* the two last ones. The problem is, that the 2TB drive does not show up in the configuration screen.:
[image: configuration screen]

I formatted both hard drives so that can't be it. Any help is appreciated.

Does it have to do with the fact that the system reserved some space on this drive? If so, how can I bypass/undo this?

Edit: larger view: http://bramvanroy.be/files/images/storagespaces.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLVED

The people on the [Dutch Microsoft forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/forum/windows_8-files/drive-toevoegen-aan-opslagruimten-lukt-niet/75ab94fc-1c28-42c4-bfc9-3269263c8086) were so kind as to help me out.

**Dutch**:
Dag Bram. Uit de screenshot kan ik opmaken dat je een schijf van 2 TB wil toevoegen aan storage spaces, maar dat er op die 2 TB schijf de opstartbestanden staan van Windows (systeempartitie). Je kan een schijf met de systeempartitie niet toevoegen aan storage spaces. In dat geval dien je eerst in de bios de opstartvolgorde te veranderen zodat er van de schijf met Windows wordt gestart.

Dan kan je echter niet zomaar opstarten want nu ontbreken de opstartbestanden op de Windows schijf (die stonden op de 350 MB systeempartitie. Daarvoor dien je dan van de Windows 8 DVD te starten en opstartherstel uit te voeren om deze opnieuw aan te maken. Dan zal de 2TB schijf beschikbaar worden in Storage Spaces.

**Translation**:
I can see that you are trying to add a 2TB drive to Storage Spaces. That drive contains boot files of Windows (a boot partition), as you can see in the screenshot. **You cannot add a drive that contains (a) boot partition(s) to Storage Spaces.**

(Free translation, added own input): a solution is to edit the boot order of your hard drives so that your `C:\` drive is first. `C:\` being the drive on which Windows is installed. (You can also unplug every drive other than the `C:\` drive) When you restart your PC, it will give you a boot failure. Restart with the Windows installation disk inserted and run *Start up repair* (which in Windows 8 is basically reduced to: *look for and automatically fix problems*). This will create a boot partition on your `C:\` drive.

Hope it helps! Credits to Dominique on the aforementioned forum!